# TagHelper rendered incorrectly in ASP.NET Core 1.1

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, tag-helpers, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I have a tag helper I crafted like this:

```
public class GooglePlusOneTagHelper : TagHelper {
   [ViewContext]
    public ViewContext ViewContext { get; set; }
    public string Size { get; set; }
    public string Annotation { get; set; }

    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output) {
        output.TagMode = TagMode.StartTagAndEndTag;
        output.TagName = "div";

        var request = ViewContext.HttpContext.Request;
        var absoluteUri = string.Concat(
            request.Scheme,
            "://",
            request.Host.ToUriComponent(),
            request.PathBase.ToUriComponent(),
            request.Path.ToUriComponent(),
            request.QueryString.ToUriComponent());

        output.Attributes.SetAttribute("class", "g-plusone");

        string size = Size.ToLower().Trim() ?? "";
        if (size == "small" || size == "medium" || size == "tall")
            output.Attributes.SetAttribute("data-size", size);

        string annotation = Annotation.ToLower().Trim() ?? "";
        if (annotation == "none" || annotation == "inline")
            output.Attributes.SetAttribute("data-annotation", annotation);

        output.Attributes.SetAttribute("data-href", absoluteUri);
    }
}
```

And when I put this code in a view:

```
<google-plusone size="medium" annotation="bubble"  />
```

It gets rendered in the view like this:

```
<google-plusone size="medium" annotation="bubble"  >
```

So, the tag helper is somehow not processing it as it must really output a DIV. Additionally it transforms my raw tag from a self-closing to one that is open and never closes!

Comment: I think I remembered, that you'd can't use empty/self-closing tags for that (if you want to add content to a tag via taghelper). Try `<google-plusone size="medium" annotation="bubble"></google-plusone>`

Comment: It cannot be used to render a DIV with empty content BUT with attributes? @Tseng

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39488954/455493) and the associated GitHub issues, where content won't be rendered correctly with self-closing tags (i.e. `<span asp-validation-for="UserName" class="text-danger" />` won't display validation message but `<<span asp-validation-for="UserName" class="text-danger"></span>` will, notice the closing `</span>`.

Comment: Basically the rule of thumb is, if you want to render content inside a tag, it must not be self-closing `<div asp-something/>` vs `<div asp-something></div>`.

Comment: but I am not rendering content, it should render as <div att="xx" att1="yyy"></div>

Comment: That **is**  the content of `<google-plusone></google-plusone>`, the only difference is that the original tag will be discarded and only the content rendered. Just add a closing tag and make sure you have `[HtmlTargetElement("google-plusone")]` added as Anuraj pointed out in his answer. The critical point is that the tag helper tags/tags containing attributes that do something with the content **are not self-closing**. At some point you'll call `output.Write(...)` in your code, that is the point when you write to the tags content. But if its closed, then you can't and generate invalid html

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the Tag Helper is not getting rendered properly. Here is the things you can verify.

1. Hope you added `@addTagHelper *, <Your Assembly Name>` in your _ViewImports.cshtml file. If not you need to add it.
2. Include the reference of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers` in your project file.
3. Add `[HtmlTargetElement("google-plusone")]` attribute to your Tag Helper.

Here is the HTML output for me

`<div class="g-plus" data-action="share" data-href="http://localhost:5000/"></div>`

And here is the screenshot.[image: Google Plus Tag Helper]

Comment: Strange, I can use all other tag helpers defined in the same external DLL but this one just does not work and I have done all of the above.

Answer (score 0):

Tag helpers translate Pascal-cased C# class names and properties for tag helpers into lower kebab case.

Therefore, for your `GooglePlusOneTagHelper` in Razor, you will write `<google-plus-one />`, not `<google-plusone />`.

If you want to use `<google-plusone />`, add `[HtmlTargetElement("google-plusone")]` attribute to your Tag Helper, as suggested by @Anuraj.